# OpenCL Kernel fails to compile

Tags: c, multithreading, opencl, parallel-processing, gpu

I keep reading and reading this matrix multiplication kernel code and I just don't get why the call to `clBuildProgram` returns `CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE`. Here is my kernel code:

```
__kernel void MatMulKernel(__global const float* A, 
                           __global const float* B, 
                                          float* C, 
                                    const int size1, 
                                    const int size2, 
                                    const int size3) 
{   
    int k = get_global_id(0);
    int i;

    int line = k / size3;
    int column = k % size3;

    float partial = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size2; i++)
    {
        partial += A[line * size2 + i] * B[i * size3 + column];
    }

    C[k] = partial; 
}
```

Can anyone spot the problem? Thank you.

Note: The code that does the initializations is correct, as I have tested with other kernels and they compile correctly.

**Edit**: Ok prunge's answer did the trick, but now I'm running into a different problem. The kernel execution actually causes a crash. Here is the code:

```
err = clSetKernelArg(hKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&hDeviceMemA);
err = clSetKernelArg(hKernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&hDeviceMemB);
err = clSetKernelArg(hKernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&hDeviceMemC);
err = clSetKernelArg(hKernel, 3, sizeof(cl_int), (void *)&s1);
err = clSetKernelArg(hKernel, 4, sizeof(cl_int), (void *)&s2);      
err = clSetKernelArg(hKernel, 5, sizeof(cl_int), (void *)&s3);  

cl_event events[1];
// execute kernel
start = clock();
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(hCmdQueue, hKernel, 1, 0, (const size_t *)BENCH_SIZE_COMP, 0, 0, 0, &events[0]);       
clWaitForEvents(1, events);
```

All err values for the calls to `clSetKernelArg` are `CL_SUCCESS`. When the program reaches `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` it crashes.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. My localWorkSize parameter is 0... So many dumb mistakes. :(

Comment: local_work_size can be a NULL value in which case the OpenCL implementation will determine how to be break the global work-items into appropriate work-group instances. So passing 0 should not cause a crash.

Comment: @vocaro you are right. I worked some more on the code and the actual problem was that globalWorkSize was not a multiple of localWorkSize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the error I got:

> error: kernel pointer arguments must
>             point to addrSpace global, local, or constant

The `float* C` parameter should probably be `__global`.  All kernel pointer arguments need an address space qualifier.

Comment: D'oh how the heck did I miss that? Thanks alot.